# Link in JS dropdown menu does not redirect

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

So I have had at this all day, but not being a good JS coder it lead me here.

When I click on the link in the dropdown menu leading to "test.html" nothing happens. It redirects nowhere, even if the browser clearly shows that it is the "test.html" link that is active on hovering.

Here is the JS code.

```
var timeout    = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

function headermenu_open(event)
{
   headermenu_canceltimer();
   headermenu_close();
   var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
    if(submenu){
        ddmenuitem = submenu.css('visibility', 'visible');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function headermenu_close()
{  if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.css('visibility', 'hidden');}

function headermenu_timer()
{  closetimer = window.setTimeout(headermenu_close, timeout);}

function headermenu_canceltimer()
{  if(closetimer)
   {  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
      closetimer = null;}}

$(document).ready(function()
{  $('#headermenu li').bind('click', headermenu_open);
   $('#headermenu > li').bind('mouseout',  headermenu_timer);
   $('#headermenu > li').bind('mouseover', headermenu_canceltimer);
});


document.onclick = headermenu_close;
```

And this is a part of the menu.

```
<ul id="headermenu">
    <li><a href="#">Høyttalere</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="pages/test.html">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

If anyone has the right snippet to add or can see a mistake in the code I will be extremely happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of this line of code

```
if(submenu){
   ddmenuitem = submenu.css('visibility', 'visible');
   return false;
}
```

It goes into this block and **return false**

Which is equivalent of calling `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` because of which the link does not follow.

Also

`if(subMenu)` // returns **truth y** value.. As it is a empty **jQuery Object**

A better check would be is to check the length

```
if(subMenu.length)
```

**Code**

```
function headermenu_open(event){

   event.stopPropagation(); // need to stop the Propagation first
   headermenu_canceltimer();
   headermenu_close();
   var submenu = $(this).find('ul');
    if(submenu.length){
        ddmenuitem = submenu.css('visibility', 'visible');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upkdM/)**

Comment: Fantastic! Spot on, and worked like a charm. Thank you so so much!

Comment: @FredBerentsen.. Glad to have helped :)